# how do I wget an .sh file and automatically run it with puppet?

Tags: heroku, puppet

I have some projects I need to do with heroku.

I'm examining vagrant for virtualized dev environment which i could just kill when the project is done.

I want some packages to be installed automaticaaly when vagrant machine starts, and I'm looking at puppet for this.

I want to start with just installing heroku tollbelt, but can't see how its done
the command I wnat to run is:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

Puppet commands are a bit not intuative.

How can I wrap it in a puppet manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write it in an exec.

```
exec { "getheroku" :
    command => "wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh",
    path => "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin",
    onlyif => "Someway you need to check the file doesn't exist already",
    notify => Exec["install heroku"], # Point to an exec which will run install.sh
}
```

Comment: Rather than `onlyif`, you can use the `creates` argument to prevent the exec from running on repeat invocations.